# biblatex IEEE citeauthor with "et al." results in intersentence spacing

Tags: spacing, biblatex, ieee-style

I am using the biblatex IEEE style. If I cite the authors of a bib entry using `\citeauthor` and there are multiple authors, the *et al.* is correctly added to the cited name. However, I am seeing an intersentence spacing after the period. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{Foo2010,
 author = {Foo, King Chun and Jiang, Zhen Ming and Adams, Bram and Hassan, Ahmed E. and Zou, Ying and Flora, Parminder},
 booktitle = {10th International Conference on Quality Software (QSIC), 2010},
 doi = {10.1109/QSIC.2010.35},
 editor = {Wang, Ji and Chan, W. K. and Kuo, Fei-Ching},
 isbn = {978-0-7695-4131-0},
 location = {Piscataway, NJ},
 pages = {32--41},
 publisher = {IEEE},
 title = {Mining Performance Regression Testing Repositories for Automated Performance Analysis},
 year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{test}

\title{TEST}
\author{TEST}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{TEST}
This a test where \citeauthor{Foo2010} has a problem with spaces.

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Look at the space after the et al:

[image: Too much space here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake on my part. Add

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}
   {andothers = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot}}
```

for the present: fix to CTAN later today.